# Assigning values in group of Labels by using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I want to check array(Tuple) of values with its name(key) conditions and assign its value(value) into a label values by using LINQ.

Here is my code to create a Tuple with Name and Value as (Item1 and Item2):

```
var myString = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";
var objects = myString.Split(';').Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                      .Select (x => x.Split('|'))
                      .Select (x => Tuple.Create(x[0],x[1])).ToList();

Result:
IND 001 
TWN 002 
USA 003 
LDN
MYS 005
```

In this above code I am getting the Name and Value as Item1 and Item2 on objects . Now I want to check the Item1 with the country code. If the country code is matches with the Item1 then I need to assign the corresponding Item2 value into a Label. We need to do this for all items in the tuple(Item1,Item2).
How can we do this using LINQ?

Comment: Do you have a certain country code you're looking up (to fill into a certain `Label`), or are you creating elements for each country code? I would greatly clarify things if you could do something to show how you'd use the code you want, like `string resultingValue = FunctionIWant(..);` or `foreach (var tuple in FunctionIWant(..)) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myLabel.Text = ( object.Exists(x=>x.Item1 == countryCode)? objects.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Item1==countryCode).Item2 : "";
```

Comment: Wow! Great! I applied your code and its working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try for the single statement:

```
string code = "IND";            

var myString = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";
var match = myString.Split(';')
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Contains('|') && x.Contains(code))
                    .Select(x => x.Split('|')[1])
                    .FirstOrDefault();

label.Text = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(match)) ? match : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of country codes then maybe you want to join with the result. If you are working in web forms you could build the labels with a repeater control

```
    var myString = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";
    var objects = myString.Split(';').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                          .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                          .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x[0], x[1])).ToList();

    var countryCodes = new List<string> {"CAN", "IND", "TWN", "USA"};

    countryRepeater.DataSource = from countryCode in countryCodes
        join @object in objects on
            countryCode equals @object.Item1
        select new {Code = countryCode, Value = @object.Item2};
    countryRepeater.DataBind();
```

Then in your form a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="countryRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="countryCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code")  %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="countryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Would result in labels:
IND 001
TWN 002
USA 003